# Можно ли задать другую папку и другой namespace для контроллеров?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня контроллеры должны распологаться так

```
root
|
-- src
|  |
|  -- presentation
|     |
|     --- controllers
|         |
|         -- public
|              SiteController.php
|         -- directory
|              SomeController.php
|
-- migrations
-- vendor
-- ...
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы в контроллерах и вообще в классах папки `src` использовать неймспейс например `presentation/controllers/public`/`presentation/controllers/directory`  без указания `src`  и `app` в пути И при этом чтобы приложение знало, что они именно в `src`?

Если в конфиге прописать `'controllerNamespace' => 'app\src\presentation\controllers',`  а в контроллерах `namespace app\src\presentation\controllers\public;`  всё работает. Но мне не нравится это `app\src` и `src`.

Если добавлять `'controllerPath' => 'app\src\presentation\controllers',` - то это не работает. Я вообще не знаю зачем оно нужно, потому что оно, как я понял, давно readOnly.

Comment: Не советовал бы менять структуру фреймворка, так как следующему программисту нужно будет разбираться в вашем говнокоде и он будет поливать вас х......ми ... Если нужно как-то разделить контроллеры, то просто используйте папки внутри папки `controllers`  ... Так всем, включая вас, будет понятно!

Comment: @RomanGrinyov не надо свои проблемы с говнокодом проецировать на остальных. А структура обговорена заранее разработчиками в компании, пришли к неким согласиям специально поструктуре. А также имеется code convention, который прочитает каждый.. так что можете удалить свой бестолковый оскорбляющий комментарий и идти дальше, если не знаете как сделать

Comment: Ну-с, я предупредил; смысла менять структуру фреймворка абсолютно нет, только себе яму копаете ...

Comment: @RomanGrinyov если вам что-то не привычно - не значит, что нет смысла. Смысл есть, особенно когда подстраивается код под DDD архитектуру. В любом случае, даже если это был open source проект, в нём всегда есть описание что это, какова структура и как с этим работать. На свете всё-таки не одна архитектура и один ЯП.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего это можно сделать через назначение autoload в composer (https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Получится примерно так:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "app\\presentation\\controllers\\": "/src",
        }
    }
}
```

Тогда можно использовать namespace  `app\presentation\controllers`

А можно в конфиге дописать basePath:

```
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__) . '/src',
```

и оставить `'controllerNamespace' => 'app\presentation\controllers',`

и тоже будет необходимый namespace  `app\presentation\controllers`